# Building object identity in PHP

Tags: performance, php

I am trying to build object identity in PHP so that when I have a collection of objects, each one can have a string as identifier and all of these identifiers are afterwards combined to form an unique md5 to represent the "identity of a collection".

Why? So that I can choose to skip re-execution of code when it's not needed:

```
interface SomeTestInterface
{
    public function testFunction();
}

abstract class Identifiable
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        $identity_shards = array_merge( get_object_vars( $this ), class_implements( $this ) );

        $identity_string = '';

        foreach( $identity_shards as $identity_shard_key => $identity_shard_value ) {
            $identity_string .= (string) $identity_shard_key . (string) json_encode( $identity_shard_value );
        }

        return md5( get_class( $this ) . $identity_string );
    }
}

class SomeBaseClass extends Identifiable implements SomeTestInterface
{
    public function __construct( $number )
    {
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->thing = 'a';
        $this->other_thing = ['a','b','c',1,2,3,];
    }

    public function testFunction()
    {
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

This is testable with:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++ ) {
    $class = new SomeBaseClass( $i );
    (string) $class;
}
```

For me, PHP 7.3 and WordPress, this takes ~100ms to execute.

My micro-decisions:

1. I need `json_encode` on `$identity_shard_value` because you can't cast an array to string, for example. `json_encode` is both fast in my experience and knows how to deal with it all.
2. I chose to make this an `abstract class` because `json_encode` doesn't have access to scoped classes, as such, it cannot encode what it can't find, so I must be able to access `$this` though it's weird because even in the abstract class, I still can't encode it, but I should be able to.

My main concerns with this is if I really need all these items to build my object identity or if there's another, faster way. 10000 objects in 0.1ms, although very good on its own, doesn't necessarily scale.

In essence, every single object that implements `Identifiable` in a collection that a module of my framework has will have an identity that I will then combine into a final "collection identity" to later do a check such as:

```
$collection_identity = getCollectionIdentity( $collection ); //MD5 computed from the identity of all these objects

if( $collection_identity != getCollectionIdentityByName( 'some_collection' ) {
    setCollectionIdentity( 'some_collection', $collection_identity );
    //re-execute code
} else {
 retrieveDataFromStorage();
}
```

As you can see, it checks if there was a change to the objects / collection and if so, it re-executes all the other code, but if not, it just retrieves what that "other code" generated in the past and as such, this is a way to use persistent storage to skip execution of heavy code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code is fine, and can't be sped up very much. But ....

The MD5 hash is most likely unique, it's got 16^32 (3.4e38) values after all, but once in a blue moon two different objects will have the same identity, especially if you use this a lot. This might cause very rare, random, bugs in your software. Bugs that are virtually impossible to track down.

I don't think the `__toString()` magic Method was intended for the purpose you're now using it for. I have learned that; *"You should always use something for the purpose it was intended for."*. The purpose of `__toString()` is to give you a readable representation of the object. By appropriating it now for identifying objects, you're loosing the capability to use it for its intended purpose later.

You're also relying on an undocumented property of `get_object_vars()`, namely that it will always return the variables in the same order. Will it? I don't know. It probably will, but doesn't have to. This could also change with changing versions of PHP, leaving you with a very big headache if it happens. You could use `ksort()` to make sure the order is always the same, but that will slow things down a lot.

I've also read in various places, and in the comments in the manual, that `get_object_vars()` doesn't return static variables. That makes sense since all objects of a class share the same values for these variables, but it is something to keep in mind.

The storing and checking of the identity hashes, in some collection of hashes, will probably be the slowest part of this whole idea.

Then **my final problem** wilt this code:

Properly written code would know the identity of its objects, or at least have a 100% reliable method to check this. Your code should be written in such a way that it already minimizes object duplication. This code seems the result of not being able to write good and efficient code (sorry, I'm trying to make a point here).

For instance, many objects could already have a simply ID integer that identifies them. For instance a model class, based on a database row, would most likely have such an ID. Most other classes could, if needed, have a similar way to identify themselves. Once you combine such an ID with the class name you should have a 100% reliable identifier.

If you really need a way to identify various objects you could simply add an `identity()` method to them. Something like this:

```
<?php

class MyClass 
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }   

    public function identity() {
        return get_class() . ":" . $this->id;
    }
}

$myObject = new MyClass(999);

echo $myObject->identity();

?>
```

This would return:

> MyClass:999

I agree that this is a very basic example, but it should be possible to do something similar for any class.

By writing such a specific identifier method for each class you can optimize it, which means it will be faster, and you can make it a 100% reliable under any circumstances. It is also a lot easier to debug, because you can see and read what is going on. No hiding behind mysterious hashes here.

**Conclusion:** Despite my objections I think your code looks fine. I do however wonder whether this approach will, in the end, cause more trouble than it is worth.

**Note:** There is more discussion in the comments. In the end coolpasta wrote [a response to this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221558/53331).

Comment: 100% I agree, each object should be identifiable by an id. If it was after me, each object should have some kind of unique identifier for its identity. Unfortunately we only have a randomly assigned id that changes roughly on each request. Here was my thought process: When somebody is using my framework, do I want them to implement both the function and the property for that id? No! It's way easier to just extend an `abstract` and be done with it. This is the only hack I have within the framework and knowing that, should I still dwell more on this code? PHP really has no answer for me.

Comment: Also, because it's an abstract, if the class extending it decides that now it needs a `__toString` of its own, it can just override, in which case, my original `Identifiable` logic fails, but again, there's no escape, `json_encode` doesn't have access to scoped objects, `identity()` requires too much setup code.

Comment: Ah, your framework will be used by others? I didn't know that. I can understand you don't want to burden other people with creating an `identity()` method for each class. I still don't get why you need to appropriate `__toString()`. Are you saying your code wouldn't work if the same method was called `createIdentityHash()`? The problem I have is that I don't understand your explanation about `json_encode`, abstract classes, and scoping. Then again, I haven't actually ran your code, so there might be something I missed.

Comment: When you run `json_encode` on a scoped class, it doesn't know about its existence, so if it's not in the global scope, it won't be able to find it. The idea for `__toString` came because I do `(string) $class` which instantly calls it. I think the better idea is to make my `ObjectsInMyCollectionInterface` to `extend Identifiable` and so, people are only forced to spit out an identifier, not write `use Identifiable` and then also `implements ObjectsInMy... , Identifiable`, they'll simply do `implements Identifiable` and implement the function.

Comment: Yes, so the user of your framework has implement a fast indentifier function after all? I can imagine `json_encode` has its limits looking inside classes, but I've never heard of a 'scoped class'. I can only guess what it could be. I do however have a suggestion: You could check whether the `$identity_shard_value` is an object with an identifier function, if it is you could invoke it to fully indentify the object. That would solve any scoping problems.

Comment: Exactly what I just did. I was just hoping I'd save the developer from having to setup this function. But there's a key takeaway. If I am generating a class from a factory from a base, then it also needs to be provided an unique string by the developer himself. If I just create my collection with identifiables from all new classes, this is fine to use as identifier: `return __NAMESPACE__ . 'ClassName'` since no two classes can exist in the same namespace with the same name, but if I generate them from just a `BaseClass`, then I can't use the class name since it won't be unique.

Comment: As such, I think that I will also need, when dealing with factories of base classes, to check whether or not the ID is taken and reject the generation of a class from that base if the id is already taken.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you linked to my answer since it's the actual implementation as per your theory and "object identity php" on Google will serve exactly this link so others can see.

Answer (score 4):

My initial issues were: speed & readability and as it turned out, issues with working with `__toString`.

First, a problem with my initial approach:

If my `SomeBaseClass` at some point needed to re-write the `__toString` function it inherited from `Identifiable`, then the initial functionality of me going through a collection of same `SomeBaseClass` would fall through, basically it won't be an `Identifiable` anymore because the functionality was re-written.

What I did, based on @KIKO's suggestion and it yielded me no bugs so far is create an interface that inherits `IdentifiableInterface`, like such:

```
/**
 * Interfaces that contains a single method in regards to an object's unique & persistent identity.
 *
 * @internal Mostly used by objects that are inside containers (as such, they're of the same intent, but differ) where comparison between these objects is needed.
 */
interface IdentifiableInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieves the object's identifier.
     *
     * @internal Do note that this is the object identifier which is meant for identification in the broader scope. You might have a, say, "suggestion identifier" which is specific to the Suggestions Module.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUniqueObjectIdentifier();
}
```

then, in my scoped (sub-module) functionality, I'm working with `SuggestionInterface` that represents each object that will be in my collection:

```
use Sprout\SproutIdentity\Interfaces\IdentifiableInterface;

interface SuggestionInterface extends IdentifiableInterface
{
}
```

Which basically makes any `SuggestionInterface` object also implement `getUniqueObjectIdentifier` and by nature, telling the users that this object and the likes of it are meant to be in a collection and that this state of being a member of a collection is important.

Although I pat myself on the back here, I think it's an elegant way to, through comments and inheritance (with which I kind of agree when it comes to interfaces) you can tell so much about your system.

In the end, here is how I compute a collection of `SuggestionInterface`s identity from a helper function:

```
public static function computeArrayIndetity( $array )
{
    $identity = '';

    foreach( $array as $array_item ) {
        $identity .= $array_item->getUniqueObjectIdentifier();
    }

    return md5( $identity );
}
```

The result?

```
10000 iterations:
new approach - 0.0005820830663045
old approach - 0.0020218133926392

100000 iterations:
new approach - 0.005621083577474 
old approach - 0.019490500291189
```

Of course, it's like comparing apples to pears when you see what one does and what the other does, it's like "duh", but I just wanted to showcase how I went from a complicated, slower method that was well intended to a more elegant, simpler and way faster result.

Although the speed is clearly better, the byproduct the new approach creates is non-existent and there will be no bugs due to `__toString`.

It does require the developer to setup that function and therefore it defeats the purpose of automation but I'll make a helper function that they can use to instantly generate names without having to think about it.

Comment: I linked your answer at the end of mine and upvoted yours.